# Session state maintain data after using them and pass them to more than one instance in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, session-variables, session-state

I'm using session state to pass data from one page to another, the problem is that after I close the page where I use the session data and open another instance, the data is copied to the new instace and that is missleading. My question is how to terminate the data of the session state after using it? Here is an example of how do I use session

```
  protected void cvFinalizedMethod_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ddlFinalizedMethod.SelectedItem.Text != "")
        {
            Session["FinalizedMethod_"] = ddlFinalizedMethod.SelectedItem;
            args.IsValid = true;

        }
        if (txtPhysicalRecordsArchived.Text != "")
        {
            Session["txtPhysicalRecordsArchived_"] = txtPhysicalRecordsArchived.Text;
            args.IsValid = true;

        }

        if (txtFinalized.Text != "")
        {
            if (txtFinalized.Text != "" && ddlFinalizedMethod.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

How to kill the session after I recieved the value in the next page?

Comment: With `Session.Abandon()` or `Session.Remove("mySession")`.

Comment: How to ensure that the session will be removed only after I have used it?

Comment: How about removing it after you have used it?

Comment: @ VDWWD please take a look at my code maybe it is easier to undestand the exact problem.

Comment: That does not make things clearer. You are only setting Sessions, not using them somewhere.

Comment: Set the Session var to null. Session["varName"] = null;